# How to make bash history prefix-sensitive?

Tags: bash, command-history

How can I make pressing up/down on bash bring up the last command that started with the prefix I already entered?

E.g.

```
$ ls foo
$ echo hello
$ ls <UP_ARROW>
```

Clicking UP after entering ls should bring up "ls foo" and not "echo hello"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few possibilities:

1. Bind the `history-search-backward/forward` commands. I believe this is closest to what you want:

   ```
   bind '"\e[A":history-search-backward'
   bind '"\e[B":history-search-forward'
   ```
2. Use the history i-search. This is probably bound to `^R`. On an empty line, `^Rls<space>` will get you back to `ls foo`, then `^R` again will take you to the last `ls` command (or other command with `ls` somewhere in the line) before `ls foo`, etc...
3. Bind the `magic-space` command: `bind SPACE:magic-space`. Then type (on an empty line) `!ls<space>`, and readline will perform history substitution automatically, leaving you with `ls foo`.

Comment: Thanks. I took option 1, and with the help of this old answer, realized that \e[B will bind the down arrow.

Comment: I edited your question to include history-search-forward (well, submitted an edit to the edit queue)